# How to make FFmpeg convert a PNG sequence into a WEBP sequence, instead of making a single animated WEBP

Tags: ffmpeg, png, webp

This command converts a PNG sequence into a JPG sequence:

`ffmpeg -i in/%8d.png out/%8d.jpg`

However, when using the same command with WEBP:

`ffmpeg -i in/%8d.png out/%8d.webp`

It will put all frames into a single WEBP, which is animated.

I have not found a way to tell ffmpeg to instead create one WEBP per input PNG.

Is this somehow possible? I'd like to avoid using any shell scripting/loops.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add `-c:v libwebp` to output individual image files:

```
ffmpeg -i in/%8d.png -c:v libwebp out/%8d.webp
```

Otherwise the encoder *libwebp_anim* will be used and you will get a single, animated WebP file.